# How can a method take an output parameter of an interface type?

Tags: go

Given:

```
type Savable interface {}
type Customer struct {} // satisfies 'Savable'

func GetSaved(id string, s Savable) {
  // somehow get a reference to the object from cache
  s = cachedObject 
  // alternately, something like:
  // json.Unmarshal(jsonFromDisk, &s)
}

func Foo() {
  c := Customer{}
  GetSaved("bob", &c)
}
```

Trying a few configurations, I either get compilation errors related to "Expects *Savable, found *Customer", or the `GetSaved` function doesn't actually change what I want to be the 'output variable'. Is this doable, and I'm just not getting the right mix of interface/pointers/etc? Or is this not possible for some reason?

Edit: A [working example](https://play.golang.org/p/XaorjumFCnY) illustrating the problem.

Comment: The above example works perfectly for me on Go Playground https://play.golang.org/p/fnCJ81C6nSK. What are you planning to acheive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works I converted it to bytes and Unmarshaled it back into your structure. Hope this helps. :)
    package main

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Savable interface{}
type Customer struct {
    Name string
} // satisfies 'Savable'

func GetSaved(id string, s Savable) {
    // somehow get a reference to the object from cache
    cached := Customer{Name: "Bob"}
    byt, _ := json.Marshal(cached)

    _ = json.Unmarshal(byt, &s)

}

func main() {
    c := Customer{}
    GetSaved("bob", &c)
    fmt.Println(c)
}
```

Run link: https://play.golang.org/p/NrBRcRmXRVZ

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to set the passed interface.
Even when a struct reference is passed as interface, the underlying type info is not lost and we can use reflection.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Savable interface {}

type Customer struct {
    Name string
} 

func GetSaved(id string, s Savable) {
    cached := Customer{ Name: id }
    c1 := reflect.ValueOf(cached)
    reflect.ValueOf(s).Elem().Set(c1)
}

func main() {
  c := Customer{}
  fmt.Printf("Before: %v\n", c)
  GetSaved("bob", &c)
  fmt.Printf("After: %v\n", c)
}
```

Here is the running [link](https://play.golang.org/p/U32GZyvflhI)

Comment: That's a reasonable idea. Is it not possible to do something like `void foo(Customer * pCust) { *pCust = cachedValue; }` (the C equivilent) in Go?